# Business Intelligence (BI) on Wikipedia data

Tags: business-intelligence, wikipedia, dbpedia

**Intro:**
I am a [BI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence) addict and would like to develop a project to drill-down Wikipedia's data.
I would write scripts to extract data from [dbpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbpedia) (probably beginning by people articles) and load it into a people table.

**My question is:**
Has anyone done this before?
Even better, is there a community dedicated to this?
If it the scripts are somewhere, I would rather contribute to them than rewrite them.

**Just an example:**
In the OLAP cube of people, I can drill-down by first name, choose drill-through "Remi", check in which areas this name is used, then for all areas drill-down on gender to check where this name is popular for girls and where it is popular for boys. For each of them, I can then drill-down through time to see the trends. You can not do this kind of investigation without a BI tool, or it will take days instead of seconds.

Comment: What you want to `get` with the Wikipedia data? BI is usually related to your own business data.

Comment: @tszmiong: Updated with an example

Answer (score 1):

Check out Mahout which is a distributed machine learning library. One of the examples there uses a dump of wikipedia

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/wikipedia-bayes-example.html
http://mahout.apache.org

I'm not familiar with the exact details of business intelligence, however machine learning is about finding relevant patterns and clustering of information together. At the very least this should give an example of loading wiki into memory and doing some simple and not so simple things with the data.

Comment: If I have to load Wikipedia data, I will do it through dbpedia. They did all of the parsing work, and provide convenient datasets that are ready to use. See preview at http://downloads.dbpedia.org/preview.php?file=3.5.1_sl_en_sl_persondata_en.nt.bz2

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) server (there is an open source version) and load the [dbpedia data sets](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads) in a local machine and use virtuoso as an "SQL DB" with SPARQL (it has jdbc interface)

from your example you could load only the "ontology infobox *" and "raw infobox *" datasets

Comment: I want to do Business Intelligence, which means OLAP cube drill-down and MDX requests, so SPARQL won't help. Virtuoso is not a Business Intelligence server. What is needed is a server like Pentaho or Talend, which are designed for BI.

Comment: you could combine virtuoso and a BI server to read from the first and feed to second with java / .net and avoid the dbpedia timeout

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an open source OLAP server for that ?

Do you need to setup a DB for your datasets or rather use files ? We (at www.icCube.com) do not need DB to setup our cubes.

How large are your datasets ?

Comment: Indeed, such a project would most probably use an Open Source OLAP server and a database. Maybe Pentaho+MySQL. I didn't know you could do OLAP with just files rather than a database. I guess it means a kind of in-memory database? The volume of data is not huge compared to other BI projects. btw, my question was: "Has anyone done BI on WP data before?"

Comment: Yes our cubes are kept using an in-memory database.